# "Sign in with Twitter" button in iOS using Xamarin

Tags: ios, twitter, xamarin

I am looking for code how to hooked up "Sign in with Twitter" button in iOS. Do you guys any suggestion how to do that? I know i need to register the app with Twitter but I dont know the step after that. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest these for you:

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/twitter-login

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_the_twitter_api/

Comment: First link does not work. But the second take you to the deprecated Twitter API, then to the [Social Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/social-framework)